# access subdirectory's files from root URL in nginx

Tags: nginx

For the sake of keeping my directories organized while retaining clean URLs, I'd like to make it so that files from inside my /src/ directory are viewed from my site's root URL. I have tried a variety of solutions to achieve this, to no avail, for example:

```
 location / {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ src/$1;
    }
```

Tip me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

You can just set

```
root /my/path/to/src
```

This can either be done on the `server` level as well as inside the `location`.

Minimal example:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;
   root /path/to/src;
   index index.html;
}
```

Comment: There are still files inside my root folder I'd like to access though. I just want my /src/ path to be removed from my URLs too.

Answer (score 1):

I actually got some sleep, and realized the files I was attempting to debug with were all .php files, which don't seem to work with these nginx rules. I'm sure there *is* a way to make that work-- however I'm never going to be handling PHP within this directory so it's fine for me.

The simple solution I can now apply is this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /src/$uri =404;
}
```

which funnily enough I had already attempted before, but was prevented from using by my half-capacity brain.